# How to make bottom system navigation bar transparent in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get bottom system navigation like the image below:

[image]

I've tried with AnnotatedRegion but not working. When I try to make it transparent it gets like this:

[image]

I am not able to use the area on system navigator bar. How can I use the restricted area? I have a background image, I want to have the image also cover the bottom restricted area. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer from this GitHub [discussion](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40974#issuecomment-773517391).

In android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-beta01'
 }
```

In android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/edge2edge/MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.edge2edge

 import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
 import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

 class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
     override fun onPostResume() {
       super.onPostResume() 
       WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false). 
     }
 }
```

In main.dart

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your current widget is wrapped inside a (or equivalent) SafeArea widget!

I do think that widgets such as Scaffold have that kind of behaviour.

So if you just used a Container instead of a Scaffold, you would probably be able to draw in this area.

I used to remove all my widgets and just add a Container(align: Alignment.center, color: Colors.red) and see if it could reach the area or not. Moving this red container in the widget tree will give you hints about which widget causes the issue.

Comment: Even if I put AnnotatedRegion as a root widget still not working. I also tried using SystemChrome, there is always white background but I have no issue with status bar. It is transparent.

Comment: If you replace your MaertialApp widget with a red container does it work?

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your build function

```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
       SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.01),
        systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
    );
```